# Which hand should be used for supporting head while applying Tilak on the forehead?

Tags: culture, tilak

Which hand do i have to put on the back of the head while getting a tilak on the forehead? If someone applies tilak on my forehead, i should place my hand on the back of my head. But do I have to use the right hand or the left?

Comment: I think there is no significance in putting hand at the back of your head it is just keeping your hair away from the site of tilak application, since in earlier days people used to have a Indian hat (pagdi/mukut) which contained all the hairs of Jata of a person, they did not use to put hand but now if we don't wear mukut or hat we use this hand gesture to keep away hair.

Comment: @Yogi is correct. You don't have to place your hand behind your head when someone is putting tilak on your forehead. It is not a practice I see in South India.